# ionic capacitor run android device failed not showing data

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor, angular14, ionic6

I just initialized a mobile app with ionic when I test on browser everything works fine but when I test on mobile the app shows white screen

command I initialize the project

> **ionic start projectname blank --type=angular**

then I add the android folder with the command

> **ionic cap add android**

and finally i try to run it on real device with command

> **ionic cap run android -l --external**

results when it runs on real android device or even faulty display emulator showing white screen[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRliZ.png)

Comment: Could be the reason of anything, please show us some logs so that any one from the community can help you out

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i just initialized ionic 6 angular 14 project and tried to run it on real android device

Comment: `ionic build` -> `npx cap sync` -> `npx cap open android` -> click on icon to build to phone

Comment: I tried but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried following?

Enable USB Debugging (Android Device)
Discover USD Devices (Chrome Dev Tools)
Select Debug app - App Name
Use USB for - File Transfer
Add android:debuggable="true" in Manifest file

Comment: This way I did it too and the debug still doesn't show anything, and I only know the reason is the android operating system, because when I run android 10 it works fine, but when I run on android 7 8 then it has a white screen error and doesn't log any errors